# CoreBluetooth on Mac ( OS X Yosemite) : Huge data receving delay after first time connection

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-bluetooth

I've got a strange problem using CoreBluetooth on Mac mini. By design, my code should receive a data update notification after discovering a characteristics service once it's connected. The problem is no data will be updated if a event is triggered by hardware within very first 20 seconds.

I've test the same code in the iOS,but it all works fine without any dealy. So the question is:

Does Apple delay the -[didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:] notification after first BLE connection?

In addition, I am using a custom profile ( A self defined UUID).

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CBPeripheralDelegate/peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:):

> This method is invoked when your app calls the
>   readValueForCharacteristic: method, or when the peripheral notifies
>   your app that the value of the characteristic for which notifications
>   and indications are enabled (via a successful call to
>   setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:) has changed.

So no, it's not guaranteed that this method will be called after discovering a characteristic. You either have to call `readValueForCharacteristic` or subscribe to notifications and wait until peripheral sends a notification.

However, after discovering a characteristic, you can get its value in `peripheral:didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:error:` method.